# bash: date comparison and result steering within jq selection

Tags: bash, scripting, jq

I am selecting some data from a text log file in bash on Debian with the following command:

```
cat /mnt/WD1003/logs/sn1.log | grep 1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE | \
grep -E "GET_AUDIT" | jq -R '. | split("\t") | (.[4] | fromjson) as $body |
{SatelliteID: $body."Satellite ID", ($body."Piece ID"): {(.[0]): .[3]}}' | \
jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)'
```

Example "raw" output from the text log file:

```
2022-07-26T15:03:10.670Z    INFO    piecestore  download started    {"Process": "storagenode", "Piece ID": "DZ4HPUJE7IFLPABM47L3B5MXFIV3L5P2IBM32CXUJBYUOMJBNJBQ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T15:03:10.893Z    INFO    piecestore  downloaded  {"Process": "storagenode", "Piece ID": "DZ4HPUJE7IFLPABM47L3B5MXFIV3L5P2IBM32CXUJBYUOMJBNJBQ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T15:47:12.285Z    INFO    piecestore  download started    {"Process": "storagenode", "Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZITFKKCKWTUHGNCVWE2LYZZEPVELC6ADPMREMD5SURZVQ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T15:47:12.493Z    INFO    piecestore  downloaded  {"Process": "storagenode", "Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZITFKKCKWTUHGNCVWE2LYZZEPVELC6ADPMREMD5SURZVQ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
```

The current result is the following:

```json
{
  "SatelliteID": "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE",
  "NG6KAUMU7TP22DNGROKBU2MRRNV675QYEOJC3X2BXH4OCML6BPNQ": {
    "2022-06-28T21:24:39.646Z": "download started",
    "2022-06-28T21:24:40.002Z": "downloaded"
  },
  "IADTQX62PCZQEJRRYPCKNWX3QSPG7A3U53IBWPQRSX6ZMH6I45UQ": {
    "2022-06-28T21:32:40.597Z": "download started",
    "2022-06-28T21:32:40.893Z": "downloaded",
    "2022-07-09T20:00:10.698Z": "download started",
    "2022-07-09T24:00:10.995Z": "downloaded"
  },
  "MZEPH4JSGSAJZ72QQV4YOYYVGLER7KOQPBUB2VEANL4MPNSZDBTA": {
    "2022-06-28T21:58:56.184Z": "download started",
    "2022-06-28T22:01:26.454Z": "downloaded"
  },
  "GFATHGO2WFBZNAOQJKXYNHTFKH2T5T4OXK3BEL7U62FNK5ZRR6OQ": {
    "2022-06-28T22:08:49.765Z": "download started",
    "2022-06-28T22:08:50.089Z": "downloaded"
  },
...
}
```

I only need to have a result of the jq-query above, if the difference between a "started" and "downloaded" (or "download failed" or "download canceled") is larger than 3 minutes. If there is none, the result shall be empty.

So the target result should look like:

```json
{
  "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE": "2",
  "anotherSatelliteID": "1"
}
```

Whereof the number indicates the count of "time lags" larger 3 minutes between two timestamps per satelliteID.

There are a couple of satellites, so in the example result above we have 2 satellites having issues with 5 respective 2 time lag alerts.

One additional remark: the command should run on MacOS, too.

Please help advising how I can do that.

**Update #1:**

I've found another example from multiple downloads. I do not expect that a second download can start before the first has finished - but in that case, the PieceID should be skipped.

```
$ cat /mnt/WD1003/logs/sn1.log | grep CDTQRMUZITFKKCKWTUHGNCVWE2LYZZEPVELC6ADPMREMD5SURZVQ
2022-07-24T02:37:47.570Z    INFO    piecestore  download started    {"Process": "storagenode", "Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZITFKKCKWTUHGNCVWE2LYZZEPVELC6ADPMREMD5SURZVQ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-24T02:37:47.815Z    INFO    piecestore  downloaded  {"Process": "storagenode", "Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZITFKKCKWTUHGNCVWE2LYZZEPVELC6ADPMREMD5SURZVQ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T15:47:12.285Z    INFO    piecestore  download started    {"Process": "storagenode", "Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZITFKKCKWTUHGNCVWE2LYZZEPVELC6ADPMREMD5SURZVQ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T15:47:12.493Z    INFO    piecestore  downloaded  {"Process": "storagenode", "Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZITFKKCKWTUHGNCVWE2LYZZEPVELC6ADPMREMD5SURZVQ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9DP5RSnCqKV1eLf6N9wtk4EAtmN5DpSxcs8EjT69tGE", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
```

Comment: Does your TSV file has a header? If so, can you post it? About the PieceID `IADTQX62PCZQEJRRYPCKNWX3QSPG7A3U53IBWPQRSX6ZMH6I45UQ` that has two downloads: How do you determine which completion date corresponds to which download?

Comment: I understand your requirements, until you show the desired output.  From the sample data you posted, I cannot figure out how you come up with `5` and `2`...

Comment: @Nic3500 i've modified the example codes to better fit input / output expectations. '2' is now reflectible in the input data and '1' is just an example in order to explain the output structure, where no example data is given.

Comment: @Fravadona: I've found another example from multiple downloads and added it to the original post. I do not expect that a second download can start before the first has finished - but in that case, the PieceID should be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the PieceIDs are unique, here's a `jq` solution:

```bash
jq -Rn '
    reduce (
        inputs / "\t" |
        try ( .[4] |= fromjson ) catch empty |
        select(.[4].Action == "GET_AUDIT") |
        [
            ( .[0] | sub("\\.\\d+Z$"; "Z") | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") | mktime ),
            .[3],
            .[4]."Satellite ID",
            .[4]."Piece ID"
        ]
    ) as [ $time, $event, $satelliteID, $pieceID ] (
        [{},{}];
        if $event == "download started"
        then
            .[1][$pieceID] = $time
        else
            if (.[1] | has($pieceID) | not) or ($time - .[1][$pieceID]) / 60 > 3
            then
                .[0][$satelliteID] += 1
            else
                .
            end
        end
    ) |
    if .[0] != {} then .[0] else empty end
' /mnt/WD1003/logs/sn1.log
```

Given the following logfile for which I truncated the IDs to 8 chars, removed the irrelevant JSON keys, and marked the unused fields with `-`:

```
2022-07-24T02:37:47.570Z    -   -   download started    {"Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-24T02:37:47.770Z    -   -   download started    {"Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-24T02:37:47.815Z    -   -   downloaded  {"Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-24T02:37:48.107Z    -   -   downloaded  {"Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZ", "Satellite ID": "1wFTAgs9", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T15:47:12.285Z    -   -   download started    {"Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZ", "Satellite ID": "IADTQX62", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T15:48:13.362Z    -   -   download started    {"Piece ID": "GFATHGO2", "Satellite ID": "4EXtmN5f", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T15:48:13.693Z    -   -   downloaded  {"Piece ID": "GFATHGO2", "Satellite ID": "4EXtmN5f", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T15:51:23.789Z    -   -   downloaded  {"Piece ID": "CDTQRMUZ", "Satellite ID": "IADTQX62", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2022-07-26T16:11:30.625Z    -   -   downloaded  {"Piece ID": "MREMD5SU", "Satellite ID": "2LYZZEPV", "Action": "GET_AUDIT"}
2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z - - "missing TABs" {"Action":"GET_AUDIT"}
2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    -   -   "broken JSON"   {
2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    -   -   "not a JSON object" "string"
2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    -   -   "no 'Action' key"   {}
```

<sup>**remark:** you should have posted your input data in this simplified form :-P</sup>

The first `(...)` of `reduce` will yield something like:

```json
[ 1658633867, "download started", "1wFTAgs9", "CDTQRMUZ" ]
[ 1658633867, "download started", "1wFTAgs9", "CDTQRMUZ" ]
[ 1658633867, "downloaded",       "1wFTAgs9", "CDTQRMUZ" ]
[ 1658633868, "downloaded",       "1wFTAgs9", "CDTQRMUZ" ]
[ 1658854032, "download started", "IADTQX62", "CDTQRMUZ" ]
[ 1658854093, "download started", "4EXtmN5f", "GFATHGO2" ]
[ 1658854093, "downloaded",       "4EXtmN5f", "GFATHGO2" ]
[ 1658854283, "downloaded",       "IADTQX62", "CDTQRMUZ" ]
[ 1658854800, "downloaded",       "2LYZZEPV", "MREMD5SU" ]
```

<sup>**remark:** The `"missing TABs"` and `"broken JSON"` records are discarded by the `try catch` filter, while the `"not a JSON object"` and `"no 'Action' key"` records are discarded by the `select` filter</sup>

With the current logic the final result will be :

```json
{
  "IADTQX62": 1,
  "2LYZZEPV": 1
}
```

Comment: This is amazing, you are amazing. I've tested it against the full log file and it works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: one last question: how can i check, if the result is empty (`{}`) in an if statement?

Comment: I modified the last line of the code for it to not output anything in this case

Comment: Thx. I'm still struggling with 2 things: currently the log seems to have some unexpected entries, so jq does not work: `jq: error (at <stdin>:10816): null (null) only strings can be parsed`. Additionally I have 2 if clauses, where I want to check, if the empty result is NOT NULL: `if [ ... -o \( ! -z "$tmp_auditTimeLags" \) -o ... ]; then` and `if [[ ... && [ ! -z "$tmp_auditTimeLags" ]; then` - but both do not seem to work. But simply testing `if [ -z "$tmp_auditTimeLags" ]; then echo "\$tmp_auditTimeLags is NULL" else echo "\$tmp_auditTimeLags is NOT NULL" fi` DOES work.

Comment: #1 does `grep -v '{' file.log` output anything? #2 `if timelags=$(jq ... file.log) && [[ $timelags ]]; then ...; fi`

Comment: #1 no result; #2 thx, will give that a try

Comment: got #2 to work; #1 still crashing

Comment: A possible cause of error is that you got lines that are not TAB delimited. Does `awk -F'\t' 'NF != 5' file.log` output anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246881/discussion-between-bivvo-and-fravadona).